# Having trouble with $watch in Angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine

I'm having some trouble getting a $watch to work when testing a controller.

The idea here is that ctrl.value can be displayed in ARI format or AEP format, but the underlying $scope.model is always in ARI format. So whenever ctrl.value is changed, $scope.model is either just set to the same value, or converted to ARI format and set to that value. However, I can't get the $watch to fire when ctrl.value changes.

The relevant bits of the controller looks like this. (I'm using functions in the watch so I can spy on them in the test):

```
   .controller('EventLikelihoodController', function($scope) {

    var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.value = $scope.model;
    ctrl.renderingARI = true;

    ctrl.getValue = function() {
        return ctrl.value;
    };
    ctrl.updateModel = function(newValue) {
        if (ctrl.renderingARI) {
            $scope.model = newValue;
        } else {
            $scope.model = ctrl.convertAepToAri(newValue);
        }
    };
    $scope.$watch(ctrl.getValue, ctrl.updateModel);

});
```

And my Jasmine test:

```
    it('sets the model value correctly', function () {

    spyOn(controller, 'updateModel').andCallThrough();
    spyOn(controller, 'getValue').andCallThrough();

    controller.value = 2;
    scope.$digest();

    expect(controller.getValue).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(controller.updateModel).toHaveBeenCalledWith(2);
    expect(scope.model).toBe(2);

    controller.switchRendering();
    scope.$digest();

    expect(controller.updateModel).toHaveBeenCalledWith(4);
    expect(scope.model).toBe(4);

});
```

The test fails saying it expected all the spy functions to have been called, but they weren't.

The switch rendering function changes the value from the ARI rendering to the AEP rendering. I have other tests that verify that it works correctly (ie  ctrl.value is changing).

I'm not sure if the problem is the actual watch statement, or if it's just an issue running it in the test (I haven't written enough code to check if the controller works outside of a test yet...)

Comment: shouldnt your watch be this  `$scope.$watch(ctrl.getValue(), ctrl.updateModel());`

Answer (score 0):

I think your watch statement should be as mentioned below as the `this` inside the function is not referring your controller's this. lets bind it manullay

```
   $scope.$watch(angular.bind(this,ctrl.getValue), ctrl.updateModel);
```

***Plus in the `updateModel()` we are updating `$scope.model` and we are listening for the changes in `value` . `this.value` has to be updated in the `updateModel()`. (this is applicable only if this the method which is supposed to change the value of `ctrl.value`***

Comment: I don't think so - the examples in the [Angular Docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/docs/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) pass in functions rather than function calls. I did try it that way though, just in case, and got the same result.

Comment: @velocipede here is a jsfiddle demonstrating the same https://jsfiddle.net/divm/nrfc212c/